# Why does my static std::vector erases when used from a class?

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have a `static std::vector` in one header to save the report of some behavior, but for some reason the `vector` erases when i want to consult it. NOTE: to make this bug work, this have to be separated in 4 files:

`Reports.hpp`

```
#ifndef REPORTS_HPP_INCLUDED
#define REPORTS_HPP_INCLUDED
#include <vector>

static std::vector<int> reports;

#endif // REPORTS_HPP_INCLUDED
```

So `reports` is the `std::vector` to modify.

`Modifier.h`

```
#ifndef MODIFIER_H
#define MODIFIER_H

class Modifier
{
public:
    Modifier() = default;
    void report();
};

#endif // MODIFIER_H
```

`Modifier.cpp`

```
#include "Modifier.h"
#include "Reports.hpp"
#include <iostream>

void Modifier::report(){
    //std::cout << "Now reports is at: " << reports.size() << std::endl;
    //uncomment the code above if you want to see that reports IS modified.
    reports.push_back(0);
}
```

Then finally when the code makes no sense to me:

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Modifier.h"
#include "Reports.hpp"

int main()
{
    Modifier m;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        m.report();
    std::cout << reports.size() << std::endl;
}
```

(this will print `0`, shouldn't it be 100?)

Note that if I inline the member `report()` by putting it in the header `Modifier.h` it works correctly, but not like this. I have also tried with 3 different compilers, but nothing changes.

Why is the `vector` `reports` empty after all of this? How would you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that's how a `static` object that declared in global scope works. Each `.cpp` that includes it has its own, private object that's not accessible from other `.cpp` files.

If you want to declare a single object that's accessible from all `.cpp` files, you must declare it as `extern`, and not `static`, in the header file and then define it (without an `extern` keyword) in ***exactly one*** `.cpp` file.

Comment: Correct. What for `thread_local` if I want the variable to be accessible from all threads?

Comment: Then don't make it `thread_local`. The whole purpose of `thread_local` is that each thread has its own object.